# How to preload a control with images?

Tags: wpf

I am working on a WPF application where I need smooth animations and transitions between pages.

On startup, I instantiate all my controls, with Visibility : Collapsed, and when I go from a control to another, I animate the two controls and change the visibility.

My problem is on a control with several images : the first time I display it, we don't see the animation (probably because it loads the images in the same time). When I load it a second time, there's no problem.

Is there a way to preload this control in order to always have smooth animations ?

Comment: In the codebehind you can have an event handler `OnLoaded()` for when the your control is loaded for the first time. Here you can load in the images or even have the start as `Visible` so they are loaded and at the end of the handler, have them go back to being `Collapsed`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed ! thanks. You can post it as an answer so I can flag it as a solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the codebehind you can have an event handler `OnLoaded()` for when the your control is loaded for the first time. Here you can load in the images or even have them start as `Visible` so they are loaded and at the end of the handler, have them go back to being `Collapsed`.